# Error: "External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Solo acabo de empezar. Como la gran mayoría comencé con el clásico ejemplo de "hola mundo". Ya llego el primer problema: Yo trabajo sin conexión, por lo que desde el principio hice las descargas pertinentes de SDK y Android Studio.

He aquí el problema:

Gradle sync failed: Network is down: connect

[image: Error:External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered]

Luego de resolver la conexion y descargar las dependencias de grandle ocurre otra cosa: [Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/413641/204926)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no puede construir tu proyecto, por eso se muestran varios problemas como el que indicas:

> External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not
> registered

si revisas el mensaje en la consola indica:

> ```
> Gradle sync failed: Network is down: connect
> ```

Este es el principal problema, puede ser causado porque no tienes conexión a internet o porque no tienes credenciales para acceder a internet desde Android Studio, esto si te encuentras dentro de un Proxy.

**En este caso si es la primera ocasión que construyes tu proyecto es necesario conectarte a internet para que se descarguen las dependencias definidas en tu archivo `build.gradle`,** posteriormente sincronizar tu proyecto con tus archivos gradle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Comentas que te encuentras en Cuba, puedes revisar este articulo donde se muestra una opción de realizarlo mediante una VPN:

https://adncuba.com/noticias-de-cuba/actualidad/guia-de-configuracion-de-android-
studio-en-cuba

> Pasos a seguir.
>
> 1- Acceder al sitito esp.windscribe.com, hacernos una cuenta y
> descargar (gratuito) e instalar esta pequeña herramienta, luego
> iniciamos este potente VPN y cuando logre hacer conexión, lo
> minimizamos.
>
> 2- Acceder al sitito: developer.android.com, y descargamos (gratuito)
> el Android Studio en su versión más estable, mirando siempre la
> arquitectura de nuestra pc.
>
> 3- Acceder al sitito: gradle.org, y descargamos (gratuito) el paquete
> más actualizado del “Gradle built tool”, el archivo descargado tendrá
> por nombre, por ejemplo: gradle-3.3-all_2. (asegurarse que el .zip
> lleve en su nombre la palabra: all)
>
> 4- Acceder al sitito: oracle.com, y descargamos (gratuito) la última
> actualización del: Java SE Development Kit. (tener en cuenta nuestro
> sistema operativo)
>
> 5- Ahora maximizamos el Windscribe y lo apagamos; y nos desconectamos
> de internet.
>
> 6- Ahora verificamos si en nuestra pc se encuentra instalado algún
> entorno Java, si es así, lo desinstalamos y reiniciamos la pc, luego
> instalamos Java SE Development Kit descargado y reiniciamos nuevamente
> la pc.
>
> 7- Abrimos la consola de comando CMD (como administrador), y
> escribimos la siguiente: java –version, y nos aseguramos que el
> resultado de la versión coincida con la versión del Java SE
> Development Kit instalado anteriormente.
>
> 8- En la ruta: “C:\” creamos una carpeta nueva (asegurarse que tenga
> derechos de escritura) y le ponemos el nombre de: Gradle, quedando
> como: C:\Gradle, luego descomprimimos el zip: Gradle built tool
> descargado, copiamos y pegamos el contenido en la carpeta antes
> creada.
>
> 9- Luego vamos a: configuración avanzada del sistema/ variables de
> entorno. En el apartado: Variables de usuario, damos en el botón
> “Nueva” y en el campo: Nombre de la variable, ingresamos una palabra
> descriptiva, ejemplo: “GRADLE_HOME”, y en el campo: Valor de la
> variable, ingresamos la ruta donde hemos puesto nuestro Gradle, hasta
> la carpeta bin, quedando por ejemplo, como: C:\Gradle\bin.
>
> 10- En el apartado: Variables del sistema damos en el botón “Nueva” y
> repetimos lo mismo del paso anterior. Luego volvemos a darle en el
> botón “Nueva” y en el campo "Nombre de la variable" ingresamos una
> palabra descriptiva, ejemplo: “JAVA_HOME” y en el campo: Valor de la
> variable, ingresamos la ruta donde se ha instalado nuestro Java SE
> Development Kit, ejemplo: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2, y
> aceptamos.
>
> 11- Instalamos Android Studio, y al finalizar NO lo abrimos.
>
> 12- Nos conectamos a internet y abrimos el Windscribe, y esperamos a
> que este haga conexión.
>
> 13- Ahora abrimos Android Studio y esperamos a que termine de
> descargar e instalar dependencias necesarias para su funcionamiento
> (demora bastante, pero no desesperar) y crear un proyecto nuevo
> cualquiera.
>
> 14- Cuando termine les saldrá en la parte inferior un montón de
> errores en color rojo(No hacerle caso)
>
> 15- Ahora, en Android Studio vamos File/Setting/ Gradle; una vez allí
> activamos la opción: Use local gradle distribution e ingresamos la
> ruta donde se encuentra nuestro Gradle: C:/Gradle luego aplicamos los
> cambios y damos en Ok.
>
> 16- Luego, en Android Studio buscamos en la barra de herramienta el
> icono llamado: Sync proyect with Gradle Files y le damos click.
>
> 17- Una vez finalizado la sincronización veremos que todos los errores
> desaparecen, diciéndonos que Android Studio está más que listo para
> desarrollar aplicaciones Android.
>
> 18- Apagar el Windscribe y nos desconectamos de internet. Ya en este
> punto, puede usted trabajar este programa sin necesidad de internet.
> (se requerirá Windscribe y el acceso a internet solo cuando se instale
> librerías de terceros en el: build.gradle ).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Hay alguna forma de descargar esas dependencias del archivo build.granle para incluirlas manualmente? Es que el IDE está instalado en una PC sin conexión. Agradecido nuevamente

Comment: Hola @yandy  la única forma es conectando a internet, no se puede realizar la descarga de las dependencias definidas en el build.gradle de forma manual, después de descargarlas debes sincronizar tu build.gradle con el proyecto mediante : `File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

Comment: Que lastima!! quizás no pueda seguir, a nosotros en Cuba nos bloquean las paginas de android desde afuera. Igual seguire intentandolo hasta agotar todas las posibilidades. muchas gracias por su atención @Jorgesys

Comment: Lo siento @yandy !, sabes, ahora que comentas esto recuerdo que otro miembro de la comunidad hace tiempo comento era de Cuba, lo correcto es descargar desde Android Studio pero .... todo se puede jeje, dame un momento y te buscaré una solución.

Comment: Revisa un artículo en el cual se comenta una forma de realizarlo mediante una VPN @yandy deseo pueda ayudar a conseguir el objetivo!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys He logrado conseguir una conexion y hacer la descarga inicial. En mi caso vi que descargo gradle-6.1.1-all.zip en un sitio, que de hecho, puede realizarce la descarga manualmente. Esta es la direccion: https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip. Solo que ahora tengo otro error...jeje.

Comment: Pienso ponerlo como respuesta de esta pregunta, dado que es un error que apareció despues de la descarga inicial que realizo el IDE

Comment: @yandy te recomiendo realices otra pregunta con el nuevo error, pero haciendo referencia a esta pregunta.

Comment: Si, me gustaría hacerlo bien. Como hago referencia a esta pregunta en la nueva? Disculpa que te moleste con estas tonterias

Comment: No te preocupes, todos iniciamos preguntando, solo crea una nueva pregunta  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask y copia la url de esta indicando que realizaste anteriormente el procedimiento comentado aquí.

Answer (score 1):

tenemos los mismos problemas, la solucion que encontre fue utilizar un proxy en el android studio y anclar la laptop a los datos moviles y realizar la sincronizacion del gradle, la configuracion es la que sigue

```
http.proxyHost=fodev.org http.proxyPort=8118 http.nonProxyHosts=*.jitpack.io,*.maven.org
```

Suerte

Comment: si muchas gracias ya lo había solucionado por esa vía.

Answer (score 0):

Sumandome a la respuesta anterior, debes procurar por lo menos construir tu proyecto una vez cuando tengas acceso a internet y de ahi en adelante no modificar las librerias que estas usando para que no tengas problemas de descarga.

Comment: Hola. Sabemos que por la baja puntuación que tienes de momento no se te permite realizar comentarios, aún así, intenta no utilizar el apartado de respuestas para realizar comentarios. Te invito a leer como responder: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer] y a hacer el recorrido: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour]. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, en mi caso no me es posible conectarme a la pagina de android. Debo buscar la forma de descargar manualmente lo necesario. Sabras alguna forma de hacerlo?