# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

solucionado el problema de conexion en mi anterior pregunta: **[Error: "External resource http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android is not registered"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413392/error-external-resource-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-is-not-regi)**
El IDE descargó: gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
Ahora me encuentro con este error
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.2/gradle-4.0.2.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.2/gradle-4.0.2.pom
Este es mi build.grandle

```
"'// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}"'
```

Comment: comprueba que no tengas activado el modo offline

Comment: @Manuel Mato, en efecto, no esta activado

Comment: en teoría la versión del complemento (4.0.0+) es acorde a la versión requerida de Gradle (6.1.1+)... yo probaría a limpiar cachés, invalidar y reiniciar y si no va, actualizaría el complemento a 4.1.0+ y gradle a 6.5+, yo lo actualicé a la última hace unos días y perfect

Comment: Diossss no entiendo si ya tengo grandle 6.1.1 que hace intentando bajar esto gradle-4.0.2.pom ya estoy frustrado voy a desintalar y empezar todo de nuevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso realicé una migración de gradle de un proyecto y me ocurría lo mismo, lo solucioné con esta respuesta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63119364/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle4-0-1

Comment: Saludos, le confieso que me emocione cuando comenzó a descargar dependencias de grandle con la solución mostrada. Pero lamentablemente no pude ser feliz, luego de varios minutos me mostro es te error: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Comment: Ya lo logre!!!! Muchas gracias